# How to compile modsecurity on Ubuntu?

Tags: c, apache, ubuntu, module

After I followed the instructions in (Building Custom ModSecurity Modules)section in [modsecurity dev guide](http://www.modsecurity.org/developers.html) in order to compile  (mod_tfn_reverse.c) using the command `apxs -ca mod_tfn_reverse.c`, I'm still finding "fatal errors" such as `unable to find the file modsecurity.h` mentioned in the header of the C document.

Here is the link to the source on github [modsec](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity)

**Instructions I did:**

1. I am using Ubuntu 14.4 64bits (New installation with updates).
2. I installed "apache dev" package, to run "APXS" command on terminal.
3. Downloaded "modsecurity" zip file from github.
4. I extracted the zip file, then I located where the `mod_tfn_reverse.c` is.

It's path : ModSecurity/ext/mod_tfn_reverse.c

5. Then I changed the directory to the targeted file `CD modsecurity/ext`
   as  I placed the folder in "home".
6. Finally, I executed the command `apxs -ca mod_tfn_reverse.c`.

These are the instructions I did, apxs works, but the compilation fails because "modsecurity.h" declared in the header was not found, I searched this file I found it in another directory (ModSecurity/apache2/modsecurity.h).

So,  the difficulty is, how can I successfully compile that specific file and have the module done and ready to use in apache2 server.
I am also confused about what are the other archives, headers, and development tools required to:

1. to compile a custom apache module.
2. to compile `mod_tfn_reverse.c`, in my case, knowing that this is only the starting point to create custom module for modsecurity.

Comment: I would suggest asking this on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com), another StackExchange community, where you'll get more specialised help.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by the included README:

```
  apxs -I<MODSECURITY_SOURCE_CODE> -I/usr/include/libxml2 \
       -ca mod_tfn_reverse.c
```